# Why is my Xamarin app now emitting many kinds of errors

Tags: xamarin.android

The app has 9 .cs files which are configured like this:

main.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtOriginalText).Text = "Original Text";

The resource ID is in the activity_main.xml file. It hasn't had problems for several years.

Now the error I get is: The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context.

And I get this:

The name 'FindViewById' does not exist in the current context

Something is going on but I have no idea what.

Comment: You can try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it. If it doesn’t work  ,try to  restart the visual studio .

Comment: Did all that. Finally just gave up and opened an older version of the app, which compiled OK.

Comment: I'm used to having at least some idea why an error happens. But with Xamarin, I haven't the slightest idea why so many parameters are now undeclared, among other issues.

Comment: Is there any full log about this problem?